# Generate Dates in C#

Tags: c#, date

Is there any helper methods to generate Dates in C#?

For example I have a Grid which shows Date,Day of all dates between given two dates..
If i select 1/1/2013 to 2/5/2013...It should Generate all dates between these two...

I tried While Loop as follows

```
 while (startdate <= enddate)
 {         
      var calendarDate = CreateDate();
      calendarDate.CalendarDate = startdate.Date;
      if (calendarDate.DayofWeek == DayOfWeekValues.Sunday.Value)
      {
           calendarDate.IsHoliday = true;
      }       
      startdate = startdate.AddDays(1.0);
 }
```

Comment: _"I tried While Loop"_ and what happened?

Comment: It worked but I want to know is there any in built Helper Method

Comment: It's good like that. At least, there is no such thing as a prebuilt "NextDay()" method or the like.

Comment: @VigneshMurugan There is no helper function to do this.

Comment: seems a simple problem, so one wonders if your problem is around the well named e, thingy?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The question doesn't claim anything undesired happens, the OP is just asking whether there is a better way than the straightforward loop.

Comment: Here is you problem Solved:

[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exploding a range of dates with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655088/exploding-a-range-of-dates-with-linq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear what's wrong with your loop, it looks as if you just have to add the dates to a collection like a `List<DateTime>`. However, you could also use LINQ:

```
int days = (enddate - startdate).Days + 1;
List<DateTime> dateRange = Enumerable.Range(0, days)
    .Select(i => startdate.AddDays(i))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit**: since you don't use a `DateTime` but a custom class:

I don't know the class and methods involved, however, this should help to implement the same logic as you in your loop(presuming `HolidayCalendarDetail` is the class):

```
List<HolidayCalendarDetail> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, days)
.Select(i => 
{
    var calendarDate = e.CreateHolidayCalendarDetail();
    calendarDate.CalendarDate = startdate.AddDays(i);
    calendarDate.IsHoliday = calendarDate.CalendarDate.DayOfWeek == JobScheduleDayOfWeekValues.Sunday.Value;
    return calendarDate;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: was writing a very similar one ... your ansnwer's great :)

Answer (score 0):

This has already been covered over here: [Exploding a range of dates with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655088/exploding-a-range-of-dates-with-linq)

I don't think there is a built in .Net helper but you can certainly achieve it with LINQ or a while loop.

Comment: If it has already been covered, let's vote to close the question instead of answering.